# Getting 401 in angular 4 get() request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hi i am new for angular and i am trying call get method using below code and when hit this url server side i am getting 401 response is there any mi-stack in my angular code or server side problem can some one help me please

In my post man client service working fine

### code:-

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic dXNlcjoxZGNkZjI5My02Mjg5LTQ4ZWEtYjBhMC1jZGQ2MmM1MjZmNDU=');
    console.log("headers are---->"+headers)

    this.http.get('http://ceec55d9.ngrok.io/employeeDetails',{ headers: headers }).subscribe(
      data => {
        alert("success response");
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          alert("Client-side error occured.");
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");
        } else {
          alert("Server-side error occured.");
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: 401 says Unauthorized.  Are you sending the credential correctly?

Comment: off-course in my postman client service working fine

Comment: check your `token` is `correct` and same as postman and check in network tab if `token` is going?

Comment: yes i checked it is same as postman,Any problem in my angular code?

Comment: have you checked the `Authorization token` in `network` tab? It is `Basic` or `Bearer`

Comment: yes i checked it is Basic,Any problem in my angular code?

Comment: I think this is a problem with your endpoint, [see this issue](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/196)

Comment: yeah, does the `backend` has `CORS` allowed for your `IP`?

Comment: If there was a problem in Angular code, it won't return 401.